# On the relation between PDEs and Distributions on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Given a distribution $\Delta$ of dimension $n$ (continuous or smooth) in a $n+m$ dimensional manifold, can one always find a basis $\{X_j\}$ such that in local coordinates $(x^1,...x^m,y^1,...y^n)$:

$$X_j = \frac{\partial{}}{{\partial x^j}} +  \sum_{i=1}^n h_{ij}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial y^i}$$

$(j=1,...,m)$. The answer seems positive to me but the way I did it is not the cleanest way. In the following $\delta_j, f_{ij}, h_{ij}$ denote real valued functions. One can always find coordinates around $p$ such that in a small enough neighbourhood U(p):

$$X_j = (1+\delta_j)\frac{\partial{}}{{\partial x^j}} +   \sum_{i\neq j}^m f_{ij}\frac{\partial{}}{{\partial x^i}} + \sum_{i=1}^n h_{ij}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial y^i}$$

where the terms $f_{ij},\delta_j$ are functions whose sup-norm as small as required. This can be done by taking any coordinate chart $\phi, U(p)$ around $p$ s.t in coordinates

$$\phi_*(X_j)_p = \frac{\partial{}}{{\partial x^j}}$$

(for instance exponential coordinates)

Thus defining the $n\times n$ matrix $M_{ij} =f_{ij}$ if $i \neq j$ and $M_{ii}=1+\delta_j$ we see that $M$ is invertible if the neighbourhood is small enough. Moreover one can proceed by elementary row operations (using functions instead of constants as in usual linear algebra) to obtain the identity matrix. One needs to argue that there will be no divisions by zero due to the fact that off-diagonal terms are very small so after each operation the diagonal terms are uniformly close to 1 (which are terms that appear in the denominators at each step). These elementary row operations correspond to taking linear combinations of your vector field basis to obtain a new basis that looks like:

$$X_j = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} +  \sum_{i=1}^n h_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$$

I was wondering if this is true or if so there is a clearer more geometric way. I guess obtaining this through a change of coordinates is less likely to happen. The reason why I ask this is,  I want to understand the relation between distributions and PDE from the opposite point of view. That is a system of linear PDEs can be formulated in language of distributions but I am curious about how to go in the opposite direction which simply boils down to this question. Any comments on the relation between the two are also very welcome. Thanks

remark: Note that in codimension one this is very trivial. You simply consider the 1-form which annihilates the distribution and choose local coordinates s.t $\alpha = dy^1 -  \sum_{i=1}^m h_{ij}dx^j$. Then the afore mentioned vector fields readily become elements of $\Delta$ (since they are annihilated by $\alpha$) which are of the desired form.